# How to create a separate row from the fields in one row?

Tags: mysql, union-all

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+--------+--------+
| id |  col1  |  col2  |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | one    | two    |
| 2  | three  | four   |
| 3  | five   | six    |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Now I want this table:

```
// newmytable
+----+-------+---------+
| id |  col  | related |
+----+-------+---------+
| 1  | one   | 1       |
| 2  | two   | 1       |
| 3  | three | 2       |
| 4  | four  | 2       |
| 5  | five  | 3       |
| 6  | six   | 3       |
+----+-------+---------+
```

---

I can do that without that `related` column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE newmytable (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    SELECT col1 AS col FROM mytable
        UNION ALL
    SELECT col2  AS col FROM mytable
)
```

But now I want to know, how can I do that containing that `related` column?

Comment: What value are you storing in the `related` column?

Comment: @SameerMirji An identical number for the fields in identical row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `id` to fill `related` column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE newmytable (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)
    SELECT col, related FROM (
           SELECT col1 AS col, id as related, 0 sort FROM mytable
               UNION ALL
           SELECT col2 AS col, id as related, 1 sort FROM mytable
    ) x
       ORDER BY x.related,x.sort ASC
```

## [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63bfb/1)

Comment: sorry, hard to tell with just seeing the code. Can you try creating a working sample in sqlFiddle? Something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95dff

Comment: didnt now that way of create table, but looks like your problem is solve now, isnt?

Comment: My problem has been solved :-) Tnx for your attention